# Create Maven configuration on IDEA intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I using IDEA to dev my springboot app, so I create one maven configuration with the code:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

but this configuration is valid only to that project, can I make this configuration global? to every maven project that I open or import in my IDEA?

Comment: It's not possible, see the related issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148319
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152492.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij idea, you can create a custom run configuration and then save it:

Steps:

With the Navigation bar visible (View | Navigation Bar), the available run/debug configurations are displayed in the run/debug configuration selector in the Run area, 
-> go to "edit configurations"
-> there select Run/Debug Configuration: Maven

In the open dialog, put your mvn command, without mvn:

```
spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

And put a name for it (example, "mvnspringboot"), then in the Run/Debug Configuration selector, choose Save mvnspringboot.

sources:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html